# i have "list index out of range" in python, but i dont understand why

Tags: python, indexing, range

```
datos = {"nombre": "Juan","apellido1": "Perez", 
         "apellido2": "Palma","sexo": "M","codigo":"30","ingreso": "2009"}

def generar_rol(datos):

    from definiciones import digito_verificador
    archivo= open('alumnos.dat')
    zzz=0
    nombret=datos['nombre']+datos['apellido1']+datos['apellido2']
    for linea in archivo:
        zzz+=1
        todo=linea.strip().split()
        print todo[2].split('|')      #<----HERE (line 24)
        nombre = todo[2].split('|')
        nombretotal=''.join(nombre)
        if nombret==nombretotal:
            break
    zzz= str(zzz)
    Z = ["0", "0", "0"]
    if len(zzz)  >= 1 :
        Z[-1] = zzz[-1]
    if len(zzz)  >= 2 :
        Z[-2] = zzz[-2]
    if len(zzz)  >= 3 :
        Z[-3] = zzz[-3]
    zzz = "".join(Z)      
    anno=''
    for i in datos:
        if int(datos['ingreso'])<2010:
            anno=datos['ingreso'][0]+datos['ingreso'][-1]
        if int(datos['ingreso'])>=2010:
            anno=datos['ingreso']    
    rol=anno+datos['codigo']+str(zzz)
    rol= rol+'-'+digito_verificador(rol)
    archivo.close()
    return rol

generar_rol(datos)
```

and i have this error...

```
['JUAN', 'PEREZ', 'PALMA']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pinky\Downloads\TAREA 3\TAREA 3\Tarea 3\funciones.py", line 50, in <module>
    generar_rol(datos)
  File "C:\Users\pinky\Downloads\TAREA 3\TAREA 3\Tarea 3\funciones.py", line 24, in generar_rol
    print todo[2].split('|')      #<----HERE
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What are the contents of `linea` and `todo`?

Comment: It looks to me like perhaps the `todo[2]` should be `todo[1]`.. The index out of range tells you that the index `2` is out of range.

Comment: linea is:
"Juan.Perez.51@sansano.usm.cl 201341040-5 JUAN|PEREZ|PALMA M;30;2015;jualma5"

and todo:
['Juan.Perez.51@sansano.usm.cl', '201341040-5', 'JUAN|PEREZ|PALMA', 'M;30;2015;jualma5']

Comment: but according the string todo[1] is ['201341040-5']

Comment: Is that `linea` the first line in the file?  Or the only one? Maybe the function having problems with a final blank line.

Comment: try do find out what todo[2] is, either within a debugger, or add a print todo before the line causing the exception

Answer (score 0):

Index out of range means you're trying to access an element of the list that doesn't exist. The index counting starts at 0, so maybe you mean todo[1] to get the second element.

Comment: but according the string todo[1] is ['201341040-5']... and if i use todo[1] i get the same error D:

Comment: You probably have an empty line in your input.